Troubles with fs.cpSync() in NodeJS
I'm currently trying to make a folder-syncing extension to VS Code just to get the hang of extensions. Everything went smoothly for me until the point where I actually had to copy a folder to somewhere else. I looked up the best way of doing this, and it seemed that fs.cpSync(src, dest)/fs.cp(src, dest, callback) was the way to go.
After messing around with it for a bit, I realized that nothing was working. Here's a small test I wrote:
fs.cpSync("C:\\Users\\User\\f-sync\\src\\test", "C:\\Users\\User\Pictures");

Which results in:
System error
I'm very confused, as the literal description of the fs.cpSync() function is "Synchronously copies the entire directory structure from src to dest, including subdirectories and files." I'm probably doing something wrong here, since a function to copy a directory should not be erroring because the src is a directory.
Thanks for your help everyone!

cpSync copies files. If you want to copy an entire directory you need to traverse the entire tree and copy each directory/file 1 by 1.

There is a third parameter for options in cpSync(source,destination, options?), which does have a recursive property. Set it to true and you should get a copy of your source directory including all files at destination.
